# API Mongo DB and Ionic-angular project

Tags: angular, mongodb, ionic2, mean-stack

I have an ionic-angular project and an API server responsible for the CRUDS of my app. This is the structure:
As you can see, there are 3 pages: home, add-user and initial

[image: home, add-user and initial]

Through my API, I am able to register a new user.

```
exports.create = function(req, res) {
    // Create and Save a new user
    console.log("creating user");

    // create a user, information comes from request from Ionic
    User.create({
        name : req.body.name,
        lastName : req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email,
        password : req.body.password,
        passwordConf: req.body.passwordConf
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err)
            //res.send(err);
            console.log(err);

        // get and return all the users after you create another
        User.find(function(err, users) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err)
            res.json(users);
        });        
    });
};
```

Since my ionic-angular project and my API are different folders, how can I redirect to my "initial" page from my api after registering a new user successfully? I have already seen this command "res.redirect('/page')" but it does not work for me.

Comment: you mean you are trying to redirect from the server side?

Comment: yes. Is it possible?

Comment: something like https://www.joshmorony.com/link-to-pages-via-urls-with-deep-linking-in-ionic/

Comment: I don’t think so. In my API’s controller I have a method saving new users, and at the end of this method I’d like to redirect to my initial page, after saving a new user successfully.